# Compare the database compatibility_level to the server version?

Tags: sql-server, compatibility-level

I have a mixed environment of servers from 2000 to 2012, and I'd like to find any databases that have a compatibility level set less than the version of the server it is running on.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE compatibility_level <> SERVERPROPERTY('productcompatibilitylevel')
```

but that unfortunately doesn't exist. Instead I'm having to do a big CASE statement based on SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'). Any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of options that I think will work:

First, you could multiply the first two digits of SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') by 10:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE compatibility_level <>
    10 * convert(int,CONVERT(char(2),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))
```

Or, probably easier, you could just compare to the highest compatibility_level on the server:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE compatibility_level < (SELECT max(compatibility_level) FROM sys.databases)
```

FYI, you can't just compare to the compatibility_level of MASTER or MODEL, as those can be left lower after an upgrade, or deliberately changed. TempDB, however, I think is always the current version.

Comment: BTW, both these work only on 2005+. We still have a handful of  SQL 2000 servers, but I realized that I don't need to run this on them.